# how often the Google Fit sync data between different devices and how they sync?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Say I login the same google account on two devices, both are tracking my steps via Google Fit.

How often the Google fit sync the steps between these two devices?

If one device recorded 100 steps, while another recorded 200 at the same period,  they Google fit sync the data, how many steps will end up on both devices? 100 ? 200? or 300? How it works?

Comment: I use these codes to request step data (without enableServerQueries)
`DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .build()`